# Interpolate timestamps and replace empty fields in CSV files

Tags: csv, timestamps, cygwin

I have CSV files with the following elements:

```
timestamp,      data1,  data2,  data3,  data4,  data5
2015-03-16 00:00:00,    3,  3,  4,  2,  5
2015-03-16 00:10:00,    4,  7,  8,  9,  3
2015-03-16 00:20:00,    1,  23, ,   5,  4
2015-03-16 00:30:00,    3,  2,  46, 7,  6
2015-03-16 00:40:00,    4,  5,  6,  8,  4
2015-03-16 00:50:00,    2,  ,   4,  ,   2
2015-03-16 01:00:00,    22, 1,  3,  4,  3
2015-03-16 01:50:00,    3,  ,   7,  8,  89
2015-03-16 02:00:00,    44, 5,  6,  7,  
2015-03-16 02:10:00,    3,  2,  1,  2,  2
2015-03-16 02:20:00,    4,  ,   ,   3,  3
2015-03-16 03:30:00,    5,  6,  7,  4,  3
```

I would like to add missing timestamps and fill data fields with `NaN` where data doesn't exist like this:

```
timestamp,      data1,  data2,  data3,  data4,  data5
2015-03-16 00:00:00,    3,  3,  4,  2,  5
2015-03-16 00:10:00,    4,  7,  8,  9,  3
2015-03-16 00:20:00,    1,  23, NaN,    5,  4
2015-03-16 00:30:00,    3,  2,  46, 7,  6
2015-03-16 00:40:00,    4,  5,  6,  8,  4
2015-03-16 00:50:00,    2,  NaN,    4,  NaN,    2
2015-03-16 01:00:00,    22, 1,  3,  4,  3
2015-03-16 01:10:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 01:20:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 01:30:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 01:40:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 01:50:00,    3,  NaN,    7,  8,  89
2015-03-16 02:00:00,    44, 5,  6,  7,  NaN
2015-03-16 02:10:00,    3,  2,  1,  2,  2
2015-03-16 02:20:00,    4,  NaN,    NaN,    3,  3
2015-03-16 02:30:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 02:40:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 02:50:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 03:00:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 03:10:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 03:20:00,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN,    NaN
2015-03-16 03:30:00,    5,  6,  7,  4,  3
```

How can I do this? Please note that this goes on for days, not just one day. I used a day's worth of data for simplicity. I'm using Cygwin, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Miller below rather than `awk` as no `awk` implementation has any real support for timestamp parsing and no support for parsing CSV other than *simple* CSV (no embedded delimiters or newlines).

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to parse the CSV, clean up whitespace, generate the missing time-stamps, and finally replace missing values with the string `NaN`:

```bash
mlr --csv \
    clean-whitespace then \
    put 't1 = strptime($timestamp,"%F %T");
         NR > 1 {
             while (@t + 600 != t1) {
                 @t += 600;
                 timestamp = strftime(@t,"%F %T");
                 emit timestamp
             }
         }
         @t = t1' then \
    unsparsify then \
    put 'for (k,v in $*) { is_empty(v) { $[k] = "NaN" } }' file
```

The `clean-whitespace` operation removes all flanking whitespace from all fields and compresses all consecutive internal whitespace to single spaces.

The first of the two `put` expressions generates the missing time stamps.  It does this by keeping track of "the current time" in `@t` (using Unix time) and stepping it forward in steps of 600 seconds (10 minutes) until it corresponds to the time-stamp read from the input, `t1`.  For each step, the time stamp is outputted in the same format as what's in the file.  For this to work, this obviously assumes that each input time-stamp occurs at 10-minute intervals.

Since this first `put` expression generates new records that lack all fields apart from `timestamp`, we use `unsparsify` to add the missing fields.

The second `put` expression iterates over all fields and sets each empty field to the string `NaN`.

The output, given tha data in the question:

```
timestamp,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
2015-03-16 00:00:00,3,3,4,2,5
2015-03-16 00:10:00,4,7,8,9,3
2015-03-16 00:20:00,1,23,NaN,5,4
2015-03-16 00:30:00,3,2,46,7,6
2015-03-16 00:40:00,4,5,6,8,4
2015-03-16 00:50:00,2,NaN,4,NaN,2
2015-03-16 01:00:00,22,1,3,4,3
2015-03-16 01:10:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 01:20:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 01:30:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 01:40:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 01:50:00,3,NaN,7,8,89
2015-03-16 02:00:00,44,5,6,7,NaN
2015-03-16 02:10:00,3,2,1,2,2
2015-03-16 02:20:00,4,NaN,NaN,3,3
2015-03-16 02:30:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 02:40:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 02:50:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 03:00:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 03:10:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 03:20:00,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2015-03-16 03:30:00,5,6,7,4,3
```

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda, Thank you for your response. I tried running miller, both on bash & cmd, but im not winning. i keep on getting errors.

Comment: `./test_interpol.sh
./test_interpol.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
" not found. Please use "mlr --help" for a list.
./test_interpol.sh: line 4: clean-whitespace: command not found
./test_interpol.sh: line 13: put: command not found
./test_interpol.sh: line 14: unsparsify: command not found
./test_interpol.sh: line 15: put: command not found`

Comment: @dante_t Your script file is a DOS text file, not a Unix text file. You are likely using a Windows editor to write your script, or an editor that saves its files as DOS text. Such text files have a trailing carriage-return character at the end of each line (when interpreted as a Unix text file). Convert it to Unix format with e.g. `dos2unix`.

Comment: Im using Notepad++ with language set on Shell. trailing carriage issue seems to be sorted but other commands cannot be executed still. script im running has your code above and the csv file im using has the sample data i initially provided on the post. I placed mlr.exe in "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/miller" and added this path to envronment variables using "export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/miller". i dont know if im missing anything.

Comment: @dante_t Having the language set something in an editor probably only applies to syntax highlighting and default indentation rules etc.  It say nothing about the text file format. I'm pretty sure that you can [configure Notepad to save files as Unix text files](https://superuser.com/questions/701995/default-save-type-as-unix-in-notepad).  It would be even better if you switched to a Unix editor, such as nano, emacs, or vim.

Comment: i ended up retyping your code and im getting the following error in cygwin: "mlr: The system cannot find the path specified."
in cmd: "mlr: conditional expression did not evaluate to boolean."
any idea what might be causing this? and why are they different when im running the same code?

Comment: @dante_t I have tested this with Miller release 5.10.2 and 6.4.0-dev.  What release are you using (`mlr --version`)?

Comment: im using mlr 6.0.0-rc1

Comment: @dante_t I must assume that you have a typo. Consider copying and pasting the command rather than re-typing it.

Comment: after navigating the web the whole day, i tried this command on cmd:
"mlr -s test_interpol test_interpol.csv" where test_interpol is my script, and it worked. Cygwin still doesnt work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for time functions (`mktime()` and `strftime()`), `gensub()`, and `\s`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ gsub(/\s*,\s*/,",") }
NR == 1 { print; next }
NR == 2 {
    dfltData = gensub(/[^,]/,"","g")
    prevSecs = mktime(gensub(/[- :]/," ","g",$1))
}
{
    currTime = $1
    currData = $0
    while ( prevTime < currTime ) {
        prevTime = strftime("%F %T",prevSecs += 600)
        if ( prevTime < currTime ) {
            $0 = dfltData
            $1 = prevTime
            prt()
        }
    }
    $0 = currData
    prt()
}

function prt() {
    $0 = gensub(/,(,|$)/,",Nan\\1","g") # this needs 2 passes
    print gensub(/,(,|$)/,",Nan\\1","g")
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
timestamp,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5
2015-03-16 00:00:00,3,3,4,2,5
2015-03-16 00:10:00,4,7,8,9,3
2015-03-16 00:20:00,1,23,Nan,5,4
2015-03-16 00:30:00,3,2,46,7,6
2015-03-16 00:40:00,4,5,6,8,4
2015-03-16 00:50:00,2,Nan,4,Nan,2
2015-03-16 01:00:00,22,1,3,4,3
2015-03-16 01:10:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 01:20:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 01:30:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 01:40:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 01:50:00,3,Nan,7,8,89
2015-03-16 02:00:00,44,5,6,7,Nan
2015-03-16 02:10:00,3,2,1,2,2
2015-03-16 02:20:00,4,Nan,Nan,3,3
2015-03-16 02:30:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 02:40:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 02:50:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 03:00:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 03:10:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 03:20:00,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2015-03-16 03:30:00,5,6,7,4,3
```